# Data in last node replaces data in previous nodes after insertion in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a function that inserts a name at the beginning of a linked list. The problem is that data in the last node overwrites data in the previous nodes. Here is the output I get from the code:

```
    /*
    Number of names to insert:
    3
    Name to insert: 
    Tony
    List is now Tony 
    Name to insert: 
    George
    List is now George George 
    Name to insert: 
    Charles           
    List is now Charles Charles Charles 
    */
```

Please help me understand where the problem could be and how to solve it. Here is the code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct node
    {
        char* word;
        struct node* next;
    }node;

    void insert(char* s);
    void print();

    node* head = NULL;

    int main(void)
    {
        int n;
        char s[20];
        puts("Number of names to insert:");
        scanf(" %i", &n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        {
            puts("Name to insert: ");
            scanf(" %s", s);
            insert(s);
            print();
        }
    }

    void insert(char* s)
    {
        node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->word = s;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }

    }

    void print()
    {          
        node* temp = head;
        printf("List is now ");
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s ", temp->word);
            temp = temp->next;
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for each string inserted in the list.

The function can look the following way

```
void insert( const char *s )
{
    node* temp = malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->word = malloc( strlen( s ) + 1 );
        strcpy( temp->word, s );

        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
}
```

You should free the allocated memory for a string in each node when the list will be about to stop its existence.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `insert` use `strcpy` instead of pointing -

```
 temp->word=malloc(20*sizeof(*word));           //allocate memory
 if(temp->word==NUll){
      printf("Error allocating memory");
      return;
 }
 /*  Or in structure you can use an array to char  */
 strcpy(temp->word , s);                        //copy data at that memory
```

Right now problem is that pointer points to the newest string(*losses reference to previous data given*) and thus print that's when printed .

*Note* -

**1.** Remember to `free` the allocated memory .

**2.** Also when taking input in use this -

```
scanf(" %19s", s);               // reserve space for '\0'
      /* ^^^    */
```